# GWTP (GWT-Platform) and remote events

Tags: events, gwt-platform, gwtp

For a normal GWT app with RPC i use the GWTEventService for remote event listening / firing , but how can i do this with GWT-Platform.
Is there any possibility to fire events from a server to specific clients? for an chatapplication for example.

thx

Answer (score 0):

we used unique domains for each user. After user logged in we generated a GUID for user, and load it from client via RPC. And than we send an event for users using this GUID as private domain ID.

On server:

```
// in CometMessageService
public void sendPrivateMessage(final String message, final Protocol.SessionId sessionId) {
    getEventService().addEvent(
            DomainFactory.getDomain(sessionId.toString()),
            new ServerMessageEvent(message));
}
```

On client:

```
RemoteEventService eventService =   RemoteEventServiceFactory.getInstance().getRemoteEventService();

eventService.addListener(DomainFactory.getDomain(privateDomain), new RemoteEventListener() {
        public void apply(Event event) {
            if(event instanceof ServerMessageEvent) {
                ServerMessageEvent messageEvent = (ServerMessageEvent) event;
                Info.display("User Specific Comet message", messageEvent.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Be free to ask me about more details.